# Unable to set the custom css class for error message

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am trying to add a custom css class to the error message. I want to make the error message red and also highlight the input element which failed the validation to red.

Code Sample :[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W3pQt/5/)

I have set the init to :

```
 ko.validation.init({
        grouping: { deep: true, observable: false },
        decorateElement: true,
        insertMessages: true,
        decorateElementOnModified: true,
        decorateInputElement: true,
        errorClass:'error',
        errorMessageClass :'error',
        errorElementClass:'error'
    });
```

But still I am not able to see the css changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `initKoValidation()` function is never invoked and that is because your `vm.init()` is never invoked. Try this:

```
function vm(){
    var init = function () {
        initKoValidation();
    }

    var self = this;
    self.user = ko.observable(new User());

    init(); // <--- the missing piece
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your init is never called to initialize the validation -

http://jsfiddle.net/W3pQt/6/

Call it like this -

```
init();
```